# Spark temp tables not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-1.6, hive-metastore

I'm trying to run a pySpark job with custom inputs, for testing purposes.
The job has three sets of input, each read from a table in a different metastore database.

The data is read in spark with: `hiveContext.table('myDb.myTable')`

The test inputs are three files. In an attempt to not change any of the original code, I read all three inputs into `DataFrame`s, and attempt to register a temp table with `myDF.registerTempTable('myDb.myTable')`.

The problem is that spark fails with `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException`.

I've also tried:

```
hiveContext.sql('create database if not exists myDb')
hiveContext.sql('use myDb')
myDF.registerTempTable('myTable')
```

But that fails as well.

Any idea why the table cannot be found?

Using Spark 1.6

Comment: I think the issue is the `.`. I tried something similar on my machine (Spark 2.1) and got `AnalysisException: u'It is not allowed to add database prefix 'myDb' for the TEMPORARY view name.;'`

Comment: @pault I agree. I've seen similar behavior. How, in that case, do you register a table in a specific database?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think you can. I think you're stuck modifying the original code unfortunately :-(

Comment: did you try with back tick sign ` as myDF.registerTempTable(' ` myDb.myTable ` ') space is not needed though.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Same issue. `NoSuchTableException`

Comment: I haven't worked with hive so I am not of good use on that :(